# Unable to cover if conditions in pitest

Tags: java, mutation, mutation-testing, pitest

I have added two conditions in code:
n the code `if` gets covered properly, however I am not able to cover the `else if` part

```
public Optional < Flavors > callIcecream() {
    try {
        if (icecream == 1) {
            //do something
            return Optional.of(someString)
        } else if (icecream > 1) {
            //do something else
            log.error("");
        }
        return empty();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IceCreamException()
    }
}
```

I have added below code for mutation coverage

```
@Test
void getIcreamValues(){
  when(abc.buyIcream(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(getIcream(1));
  final Optional<Falvors>icecreamInfo = xyz.callIcecream();
  assertThat(icecreamInfo).isPresent();
}


@Test
void getIcreamValues(){
  when(abc.buyIcream(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(getIcream(0));
  final Optional<Falvors>icecreamInfo = xyz.callIcecream();
  assertThat(icecreamInfo).isEmpty();
}

@Test
void getIcreamValues(){
  when(abc.buyIcream(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(getIcream(2));
  final Optional<Falvors>icecreamInfo = xyz.callIcecream();
  assertThat(icecreamInfo).isPresent();
}
```

Comment: how do you set the value for iceCream?

Comment: using the value generated from function in the class:

public Optional<Flavors> callIcecream(){
try{
final int icecream = getValues();
    if(icecream==1){
      //do something
      return Optional.of(someString)
    } else if(icecream > 1){
       //do something else
       log.error("");
    }
    return empty();
 }catch(Exception e){
   throw new IceCreamException()
 }
}

Comment: that is not the code you have in your question. we don't see a value set before that method is called.

Comment: so you need the code of getValues()?

Comment: Can you post the method empty()

Comment: Since the code is in java 11 and the return type of the function is Optional, I am able to use the inbuilt empty() method

Comment: If you still need to refer the inbuilt code. It goes something like this:
private static final Optional<?> EMPTY = new Optional<>();   
public static<T> Optional<T> empty() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Optional<T> t = (Optional<T>) EMPTY;
        return t;
    }

Comment: this doesn't seem to be a mutation testing problem. You are just not being able to make your test get icecream == 2. It is not clear how icecream get set..maybe post the remaining class code?